# How to guess bitwise operations not using if else statement?

Tags: bitwise-operators

I want to get the remainder of `2^n` it means that `number % 2^n` (n is between 0 and 31).

First I think simply `(x>>n)` but it works n`>0`

```
n=0 -> 0
```

but I can't use if else statement, but I don't get any idea how to translate from if else to step-by-step bitwise operations.

Please give me any hint for this question.

Comment: Can you give a numeric example? Because it is hard to understand what is asked here.

Comment: @PaulR First version of this article has 'homework' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly then you just need to do this:

```
remainder = x & ((1 << n) - 1); // remainder = x % 2^n
```

This uses the well known property that: `x % 2^n == x & (2^n - 1)`.

Comment: Well (a) you should probably try it yourself and see and (b) it depends on how you define the modulus operator for negative values, since there is no universal definition.